# i have maore than one element with c=same classname but when i do remove or add class it is saying can't preocess remove or add classes on undefine

Tags: javascript

```
let main = document.getElementsByClassName(".main");

let main= document.querySelectorAll(".main");
```

I tried both of this.

I want selector so that I can apply add and remove classist

```
main.classList.add('d-flex');
```

Comment: you have to add while inside a loop. `getElementsByClassName` and `querySelectorAll` returns an array like object. Might need more detail if that still doesnt solve the problem, show us your HTML as well

Comment: also `getElementsByClassName("main")` no need for the dot in this method

Comment: i tryed main.foreach((main)=>{main.classList.add('d-flex');})

Comment: can you edit your question and create a snippet with your code when you can reproduce the problem that you are getting? what kind of error do you get?

Comment: i tryied with  getElementsByClassName("main") but not working undefine

Comment: it's `forEach` not `foreach`

Comment: yes i have used forEach ..not working

Comment: what error do you get then? edit your question, add more details please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should work if you do it correctly.
Get all elements with `querySelectorAll` method then iterate with the `forEach` and add a new class with `classList.add()`

```js
let main= document.querySelectorAll(".main");

main.forEach((el)=>{
    el.classList.add('d-flex');
})
```

```css
.main {
  color: blue;
  font-family: verdana;
  font-size: 200%;
}
.d-flex {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">div1</div>
<div class="main">div2</div>
<div class="main">div3</div>
```